# Integrate qrcode as a wallpaper

Tags: html, css

I'm using the following library to generate QRCodes: https://marcoagner.github.io/Flask-QRcode/

I would like to give the user the option to download this QR and set it as a wallpaper. The problem is that when I generate the qrcode, if you download the image via pressing the image for a few seconds, you only download the QRCode and when you go to your "camera roll" and you set it as a wallpaper it's something like this:

[image]

My question is: How can I set white borders around the QRcode so when the user downloads the image he/she can set it as a correct wallpaper?

This is my code:

```
  <center><img src="{{ qrcode("http://myherokuapp.com" + url_for('view', useraid=useraid),box_size=4 )}}"></center>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just realized this library has a border option, which is exactly I was looking for, so I made:

```
 <center><img src="{{ qrcode("http://myherokuapp.com" + url_for('view', useraid=useraid),box_size=4, border=50 )}}"></center>
```